# SQLite3 database is Locked in Azure

Tags: sql, azure, sqlite

I have a Flask server Running on Azure provided by Azure App services with sqlite3 as a database. I am unable to update sqlite3 as it is showing that database is locked

```
    2018-11-09T13:21:53.854367947Z [2018-11-09 13:21:53,835] ERROR in app: Exception on /borrow [POST]
    2018-11-09T13:21:53.854407246Z Traceback (most recent call last):
    2018-11-09T13:21:53.854413046Z   File "/home/site/wwwroot/antenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2292, in wsgi_app
    2018-11-09T13:21:53.854417846Z     response = self.full_dispatch_request()
    2018-11-09T13:21:53.854422246Z   File "/home/site/wwwroot/antenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1815, in full_dispatch_request
    2018-11-09T13:21:53.854427146Z     rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
    2018-11-09T13:21:53.854431646Z   File "/home/site/wwwroot/antenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1718, in handle_user_exception
    2018-11-09T13:21:53.854436146Z     reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
    2018-11-09T13:21:53.854440346Z   File "/home/site/wwwroot/antenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
    2018-11-09T13:21:53.854444746Z     raise value
    2018-11-09T13:21:53.854448846Z   File "/home/site/wwwroot/antenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1813, in full_dispatch_request
    2018-11-09T13:21:53.854453246Z     rv = self.dispatch_request()
    2018-11-09T13:21:53.854457546Z   File "/home/site/wwwroot/antenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
    2018-11-09T13:21:53.854461846Z     return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
    2018-11-09T13:21:53.854466046Z   File "/home/site/wwwroot/application.py", line 282, in borrow
    2018-11-09T13:21:53.854480146Z     cursor.execute("UPDATE books SET stock = stock - 1 WHERE bookid = ?",(bookid,))
    2018-11-09T13:21:53.854963942Z sqlite3.OperationalError: database is locked
```

Here is the route -

```
@app.route('/borrow',methods=["POST"])
def borrow():
    # import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
    body = request.get_json()
    user_id = body["userid"]
    bookid = body["bookid"]
    conn = sqlite3.connect("database.db")
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    date = datetime.now()
    expiry_date = date + timedelta(days=30)
    cursor.execute("UPDATE books SET stock = stock - 1 WHERE bookid = ?",(bookid,))
    # conn.commit()
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO borrowed (issuedate,returndate,memberid,bookid) VALUES (?,?,?,?)",("xxx","xxx",user_id,bookid,))
    conn.commit()
    cursor.close()
    conn.close()

    return json.dumps({"status":200,"conn":"working with datess update"})
```

I tried checking the database integrity using pragma. There was no integrity loss. So I don't know what might be causing that error. Any help is Appreciated :)

Comment: Something else probably has the database open and has an exclusive lock. Only one connection can write to a sqlite database at a time.

Answer (score 11):

I use Azure app service on Docker on Linux, and have the same issue. If you are using Azure app service on Windows, the problem is different from mine.

The problem is that /home is mounted as CIFS filesystem which can not deal with SQLite3 lock.

My workaround is to copy db.sqlite3 file to some directory other than /home, and properly set permissions and ownerships of the db.sqlite3 file and its directory as well. Then, let my project read/write it. However, this workaround is pretty awkward. I don't recommned.

Comment: Could you elaborate on "some directory other than /home"? I'm having the same issue and I was wondering if I could save it to something like "/tmp" while I need to operate on the file, and move it to "/home" when I just need to store it persistently

Comment: Follow up on my comment above: I think it's working.. but if anyone got any insight on whether that's a reasonable way, would still love to hear about it

Comment: Hi. I don't remember clearly, but I think I made a directory under / or I used /tmp. I think if there are no errors, it works OK.

Comment: If you store it in /tmp the file is gone after a basic restart of the AppService.

Answer (score 9):

Presumably this solution is not safe for production workloads but at least I got it working by executing the following command:

```
sqlite3 <database-file> 'PRAGMA journal_mode=wal;'
```

After running the above command, my database stored on an Azure File share works inside a container Web App.

Comment: this solution worked for me - Azure App Service for Containers on Linux with the database file in an Azure File Share

Comment: I had to create the DB file on /tmp, run the command, and then move it to the mounted volume

Answer (score 5):

I got it by setting up the azure mount options with the following configuration:

```
dir_mode=0777,file_mode=0777,uid=0,gid=0,mfsymlinks,nobrl,cache=strict
```

But the real solution is to add the flag **nobrl** (Byte-Range Lock).

Add storageclass example for kubernetes:

```
---
kind: StorageClass
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: azureclass
provisioner: kubernetes.io/azure-file
mountOptions:
  - dir_mode=0777
  - file_mode=0777
  - uid=0
  - gid=0
  - mfsymlinks
  - nobrl
  - cache=strict
parameters:
  skuName: Standard_LRS
```

Comment: I had the same problem on a pgadmin 4 container running on AKS with a pv with this kind of storage class, where in the initialization SQLite gave the error "database is locked". This setting solved my problem. Microsoft provides some reference to this in its documentation too [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/azure-kubernetes/mountoptions-settings-azure-files#other-useful-settings).
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This answer appears toward the top of a typical Google search for this issue so I thought I'd add a couple of additional tips:

For those running JavaScript and using Sequelize as the interface to your SQLite DB, running

`await sequelize.query('PRAGMA journal_mode=WAL;')`

prior to creating your database will allow you to read/write the DB file in an Azure web app running under a Linux service plan. I have a separate script that creates one via a call to `sequelize.sync()`. I'm storing the DB file in a separate directory under /home within the file system for the Linux container. It seems to run fine and my workload is expected to be very light. Note that you don't need to set the journal mode again when your app starts and you try to connect to the database, that mode will be set in the file itself (this wasn't obvious from the SQLite docs).

Answer (score 0):

that problem has disappeared for me.

sqlite3 v5.1.5

Azure Linux-Development (S1: 1)

NodeJS Web app was added with everything set by default, home is still mounted as CIFS, what might be changed is mode - 0777:

```
/home type cifs (rw,relatime,vers=3.1.1,cache=strict,username=secretuserid,uid=0,noforceuid,gid=0,noforcegid,addr=secretip,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,soft,nounix,serverino,mapposix,nobrl,mfsymlinks,noperm,rsize=1048576,wsize=4194304,bsize=1048576,echo_interval=60,actimeo=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was using the free tier F1 for the web service. After scaling up to B1 the issue was solved. After applying the migrations, I was able to scale back down to F1.