# Azure App Service: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 5 database is locked

Tags: php, sqlite, azure-web-app-service

I am getting the following error when the following code is executed from an Azure App Service:

The container used to spin this Azure App Service can be found under the following details:

> Server: https://mcr.microsoft.com Image:
> appsvc/wordpress-alpine-php:latest

```
function createStructure( $info )
{
  $contentFolder = __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '.content.' . getRandomString( 8 );
  $newDbFile     = $contentFolder . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'structure.db';
  mkdir( $contentFolder, 0777, true );
  mkdir( $contentFolder . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'html', 0777, true );
  mkdir( $contentFolder . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'binary', 0777, true );
  mkdir( $contentFolder . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'backup', 0777, true );
  mkdir( $contentFolder . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'imports', 0777, true );
  touch( $contentFolder . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'empty.css' );
  touch( $contentFolder . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'empty.js' );
  touch( $contentFolder . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'empty.js' );
  file_put_contents( $contentFolder . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '1px.png', base64_decode( 'iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABAQAAAAA3bvkkAAAAAnRSTlMAAHaTzTgAAAAKSURBVAjXY2AAAAACAAHiIbwzAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC' ) );
  file_put_contents( $contentFolder . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'empty.ico', base64_decode( 'AAABAAEAEBACAAEAAQCwAAAAFgAAACgAAAAQAAAAIAAAAAEAAQAAAAAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAgAAAAIAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAD//wAA//8AAP//AAD//wAA//8AAP//AAD//wAA//8AAP//AAD//wAA//8AAP//AAD//wAA//8AAP//AAD//wAA' ) );
  $newDb = new PDO( "sqlite:{$newDbFile}" );
  $newDb->exec( "PRAGMA journal_mode=WAL" );
  createTable( 'structure', $newDb );
  createTable( 'settings', $newDb );
  foreach ( $info['info']['settings'] as $param => $value ) {
    $stmt = $newDb->prepare( "INSERT INTO settings VALUES(:param, :value)" );
    $stmt->execute( ['param' => $param, 'value' => $value] );
  }
  return $contentFolder;
}
```

Error message:

```
Starting Live Log Stream ---
2022-04-17T09:22:08.084875633Z: [INFO]  PHP 8.0.11 (cli) (built: Oct 14 2021 22:56:25) ( NTS )
2022-04-17T09:22:08.084935033Z: [INFO]  Copyright (c) The PHP Group
2022-04-17T09:22:08.084943433Z: [INFO]  Zend Engine v4.0.11, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
2022-04-17T09:22:08.084949533Z: [INFO]      with Zend OPcache v8.0.11, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
2022-04-17T09:22:08.097821418Z: [INFO]  Setup openrc ...
2022-04-17T09:22:08.422734722Z: [ERROR]  Service "hwdrivers' needs non existent service "dev"
2022-04-17T09:22:08.423166221Z: [ERROR]  Service "machine-id' needs non existent service "dev"
2022-04-17T09:22:08.423805420Z: [INFO]   * Caching service dependencies ... [ ok ]
2022-04-17T09:22:08.442953497Z: [INFO]  INFO: Log folder for nginx/php not found. creating...
2022-04-17T09:22:08.458433778Z: [INFO]  INFO: Found an existing WordPress status file ...
2022-04-17T09:22:08.569514843Z: [INFO]  INFO: Check SSL Setting...
2022-04-17T09:22:08.574120737Z: [INFO]  INFO: SSL Settings exist!
2022-04-17T09:22:08.578651232Z: [INFO]  REDIS_MAX_MEMORY_MB must be an integer..
2022-04-17T09:22:08.583817925Z: [INFO]  Starting Redis with Max Memory: 815301KB
2022-04-17T09:22:08.583851525Z: [INFO]  INFO: /var/log/supervisor not found. creating ...
2022-04-17T09:22:08.585432723Z: [INFO]  INFO: Updating PHP configurations...
2022-04-17T09:22:08.587717321Z: [INFO]  INFO: creating /run/php/php-fpm.sock ...
2022-04-17T09:22:08.588212220Z: [INFO]  134:C 17 Apr 2022 09:22:08.587 # oO0OoO0OoO0Oo Redis is starting oO0OoO0OoO0Oo
2022-04-17T09:22:08.588236720Z: [INFO]  134:C 17 Apr 2022 09:22:08.587 # Redis version=6.0.16, bits=64, commit=2858e290, modified=0, pid=134, just started
2022-04-17T09:22:08.588245020Z: [INFO]  134:C 17 Apr 2022 09:22:08.587 # Configuration loaded
2022-04-17T09:22:08.595743311Z: [INFO]  134:M 17 Apr 2022 09:22:08.595 * Running mode=standalone, port=6379.
2022-04-17T09:22:08.596938609Z: [INFO]  134:M 17 Apr 2022 09:22:08.595 # Server initialized
2022-04-17T09:22:08.602717002Z: [INFO]  134:M 17 Apr 2022 09:22:08.602 # WARNING overcommit_memory is set to 0! Background save may fail under low memory condition. To fix this issue add 'vm.overcommit_memory = 1' to /etc/sysctl.conf and then reboot or run the command 'sysctl vm.overcommit_memory=1' for this to take effect.
2022-04-17T09:22:08.602774902Z: [INFO]  134:M 17 Apr 2022 09:22:08.602 # WARNING you have Transparent Huge Pages (THP) support enabled in your kernel. This will create latency and memory usage issues with Redis. To fix this issue run the command 'echo madvise > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled' as root, and add it to your /etc/rc.local in order to retain the setting after a reboot. Redis must be restarted after THP is disabled (set to 'madvise' or 'never').
2022-04-17T09:22:08.602889702Z: [INFO]  134:M 17 Apr 2022 09:22:08.602 * Ready to accept connections
2022-04-17T09:22:08.607710496Z: [INFO]  Starting SSH ...
2022-04-17T09:22:08.608545495Z: [INFO]  Starting php-fpm ...
2022-04-17T09:22:08.608568495Z: [INFO]  Starting Nginx ...
2022-04-17T09:22:11.059816295Z: [INFO]  2022-04-17 09:22:11,059 INFO Set uid to user 0 succeeded
2022-04-17T09:22:11.071782891Z: [INFO]  2022-04-17 09:22:11,071 INFO supervisord started with pid 145
2022-04-17T09:22:12.078339674Z: [INFO]  2022-04-17 09:22:12,077 INFO spawned: 'php-fpm' with pid 147
2022-04-17T09:22:12.087204670Z: [INFO]  2022-04-17 09:22:12,086 INFO spawned: 'delay' with pid 148
2022-04-17T09:22:12.095654167Z: [INFO]  2022-04-17 09:22:12,089 INFO spawned: 'nginx' with pid 149
2022-04-17T09:22:12.098493065Z: [INFO]  2022-04-17 09:22:12,098 INFO spawned: 'sshd' with pid 150
2022-04-17T09:22:12.107153962Z: [INFO]  2022-04-17 09:22:12,106 INFO spawned: 'watch-log-files' with pid 152
2022-04-17T09:22:14.016132270Z: [INFO]  2022-04-17 09:22:14,015 INFO success: php-fpm entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2022-04-17T09:22:14.016186470Z: [INFO]  2022-04-17 09:22:14,016 INFO success: delay entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2022-04-17T09:22:14.016538270Z: [INFO]  2022-04-17 09:22:14,016 INFO success: nginx entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2022-04-17T09:22:14.016786670Z: [INFO]  2022-04-17 09:22:14,016 INFO success: sshd entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2022-04-17T09:22:14.016891269Z: [INFO]  2022-04-17 09:22:14,016 INFO success: watch-log-files entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2022-04-17T09:22:15.610369307Z: [INFO]  2022-04-17 09:22:15,609 INFO exited: sshd (exit status 0; expected)
2022-04-17T09:22:17.112204781Z: [INFO]  2022-04-17 09:22:17,111 INFO exited: delay (exit status 0; expected)
2022-04-17T09:23:38  No new trace in the past 1 min(s).
2022-04-17T09:24:03.643278984Z: [ERROR]  2022/04/17 09:24:03 [error] 165#165: *10 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 5 database is locked in /home/site/wwwroot/load/load.php:1121
2022-04-17T09:24:03.643317984Z: [ERROR]  Stack trace:
2022-04-17T09:24:03.643326084Z: [ERROR]  #0 /home/site/wwwroot/load/load.php(1121): PDO->exec('PRAGMA journal_...')
2022-04-17T09:24:03.643332684Z: [ERROR]  #1 /home/site/wwwroot/load/load.php(6571): createStructure(Array)
2022-04-17T09:24:03.643338184Z: [ERROR]  #2 {main}
2022-04-17T09:24:03.643343684Z: [ERROR]    thrown in /home/site/wwwroot/load/load.php on line 1121" while reading response header from upstream, client: 169.254.142.1, server: _, request: "POST /load/load.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php-fpm.sock:", host: "--------.azurewebsites.net"
```

Comment: How did you try to solve the problem? Describe your attempts and how they failed. Once you showed, that you spent energy on the problem, people are more willing to help. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users

Answer (score 0):

Probably this:

> The underlying storage is NFS/CIFS which is why SQLite isn't advise on a storage mount. The best workaround is to leverage either PostgreSQL or MySQL.

([ref](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/47130#issuecomment-1075237531))

[Existing Q&A exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53226642/sqlite3-database-is-locked-in-azure), something that may be no news to you.

---

On the script level:

The solution is to catch the exception and deal with it. E.g. make the script work with the error condition the DB is not available.

Then make it configurable, try the different configurations that may or may not work around your issue and finally have the option to use a DB *or* a storage service which is intended to work.